# Finding the volume of the region bounded by xy-plane the paraboloid and the elliptic cylinder

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, upper-lower-bounds, jacobian

find the volume of the region bounded by xy-plane the paraboloid $z =  x^2+y^2$ and the elliptic cylinder $\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4} =  1$

[image]

lets use elliptical coordinates:

$$x=3rcos\theta $$
$$y = 2rsin\theta$$

Let's find the Jacobian:

$$\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (r,\theta)} = 6r  $$

now, my question is what is the function of the volume bounded by the paraboloid and cylinder should we subtract both functions?

$$\int^? \int^? (?)6rdrd\theta$$

also I don't know how to find the bounds

Comment: The Jacobian of *what*?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos elliptical coordinates I already update the question.

Comment: Judging by your diagram it looks like $\theta$ goes from 0 to $2 \pi$ and $r$ from 0 to 1.

Comment: @Blitzer why do you think that for r?

Comment: because x^2/9+y^2/4 transforms into r^2, so the edge of the ellipse is r=1.

Comment: @Blitzer what about the function that bound the volume?

Comment: Oh yes - good point. Perhaps you should calculate the volume within the ellipsoid and the paraboloid separately and subtract. You'll have to cut it off for some large value of z and then take the limit.

Comment: @Blitzer I thought you could do the same that in 2d subtract the two functions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147945/discussion-between-blitzer-and-sirmrpirateroberts).

Comment: @Blitzer have you come out with any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be the volume of the region and $E$ be the intersection of the elliptic cylinder with the $xy$-plane. Then $V=\int\int_{E} z dE$. We parametrize $E$ by elliptical coordinates $(r,\theta)\in F$, where $F=[0,1]\times [0,2\pi]$ putting $x=3r\cos\theta $ and $y = 2r\sin\theta$. Then  $\int\int_{E} z dE=\int\int_{F} z |J(r,\theta)|dF$, where $J(r,\theta)=\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (r,\theta)} = 6r$. Thus
$$V=\int\int_{F} z |J(r,\theta)|dF=\int_{0}^1 dr \int_{0}^{2\pi} (9r^2\cos^2\theta+4r^2\sin^2\theta)\cdot 6r d\theta=$$
$$\int_{0}^1 dr \left(54r^3\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^2\theta d\theta+24r^3\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin^2\theta d\theta\right)=$$
$$\int_{0}^1 dr \left(54r^3\pi +24r^3\pi\right)= \int_{0}^1 78r^3\pi dr=\frac{39\pi}2.$$

Comment: that makes sense, I thought we have two subtract the ellipse from the paraboloid to get the bounded function